# How do I generate combinations faster than with nested for loops?

Tags: c++, performance, loops, for-loop

For example, if I want to generate all the possible combinations of a list of numbers length 4, where the numbers are between 0 and 10, what would be a faster way to do that than with 4 nested for loops? (if there is one)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
      for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++){
         for (int l = 0; l < 11; l++){
            
            // more code using the combinations here
            
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely you'll find a faster method. Each of those loops is only a few machine instructions.  Of course you could parallelize, but that can complicate whatever is consuming the combinations: the inner loop body.

Comment: Also, in the interests of readability, try using more descriptive names than `i`, `j`, `k`, and `l`.    The compiler doesn't care, but it helps programmers understand/maintain the code.     And, for using a variable named `l` in code with hard-coded values of `11`, wash your mouth out with soap.

Comment: Maybe `for (int ijkl = 0; ijkl < 11*11*11*11; ijkl++) {` depending on what `// more code using the combinations here` does.